# MYSQL and unique keys

Tags: mysql, unique-index

Very beginner question:

I write user registration data into a mysql table with columns: id, name, password, email....

To prevent duplicate emails, I have set a unique index on "email" and am checking for error  23000 in the php code, i.e. for duplicate emails. This works so far fine, however if I delete a user (i.e. one row in the user table) in phpmyadmin and try to re-register with the same email address, it gives me the 23000 error ("duplicate email") even though this email address has been deleted.

Do I need to do anything special (flush tables?...) in order to "refresh" the unique index on email?

Comment: That should not happen (once the record was deleted it's gone and it should not interfere anymore), so please add your code to the question as the problem is probably situated elsewhere.

Comment: make sure you committed the delete too.

Comment: What do you mean by "commit the delete"? I have autocommit set to on.

Comment: Could it be that the duplicate emails somehow made it to the table before the unique constraint was enabled? In any event, can't you just verify the presence of the email with something like `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE email = '...'` in PHPMyAdmin or whatever tool you are using for debugging/diagnostics?

Comment: run this query `SELECT email FROM <table_name>;` Do you see the email that you deleted?